# How to make checkboxes checked at run time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I constructing check boxes at run time using `ng-repeat` check HTML code-

```
div data-ng-repeat="data in cntrl.columndetailsOnLoad">
            {{data.displayName}} <input type="checkbox" id="{{data.id}}" data-ng-model="cntrl.check[data.id]" {{data.checked}}><br>
```

object data has property `"checked" :"checked"` , But it is not working .

```
object structure -{
       "id": "value.cycleStatus",
       "status": "1",
       "position": "1",
       "displayName": "Status"
   },
```

Comment: "_object data has property "checked" :"checked"_" Where? The object you showed us does not.

Answer (score 0):

you can bind a value to object with  `ng-model="x"`, and set the value of x to preferred check inside controller.